# Creating a function in python to get multiple data assembled into one dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, yfinance

I have extracted multiple stock data from yahoo finance by using yfinance api by using

```
prices0= yf.download(' '.join(sample.iloc[0]),start,end)['Adj Close']
returns0= prices0.pct_change()[1:]`

prices1= yf.download(' '.join(sample.iloc[1]),start,end)['Adj Close']
returns1= prices1.pct_change()[1:]

prices2= yf.download(' '.join(sample.iloc[2]),start,end)['Adj Close'] 
returns2= prices2.pct_change()[1:]
```

from a dataframe named *sample* containing the relevant 3 stock name of a 3 stock portfolio

Now I wish to define a function which just accepts the number at end of "returns**n**" above in the code and prints out the mean of the returns

This problem is just using the number at end of a variable x to identify the data inside the variable
i.e. x2 is a variable identified in the function by '2' in the arguments within the function defined
and then performing some action on the data and printing the output

I hope I make some sense I tried to put my problem in simple layman words.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having three variables, put your dataframes in a dictionary

```
d = {'prices1': prices1, 'prices2': prices2, 'prices3': prices3'}
```

and then apply your function to `d['pricesX]`.

Comment: I tried it I am not able to implement the referencing of dictionary inside the function , p = {'0': prices0, '1': prices1,'2': prices2, '3': prices3,'4': prices4 , '5': prices5 , '6': prices6 , '7': prices7 , '8': prices8 , '9': prices9} , this is how i have constructed the dictionary , now I wish to make a function called as returns(n) which only takes argument n which corresponds to the key 'n' inside the dictionary.

Comment: You could create a function like `def returns(n): return p[n]`. However, using `p[n]` directly is much easier.